# JavaScript partially match string inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```
const arr = ['be-', 'fe-', 'automated'];

const str = 'fe-cheese';
const oi = arr.includes(str) ? 'cheese' : 'meat';

console.log(oi);
```

I have an array of partial matches and I want to check to see if the string contains any of the partials in the `arr`.

The above returns `meat` when it should match `fe-` and return `cheese`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). It will iterate over an array and return true if **any** of the iterations return true. *Note:* This has the added benefit of short-circuit execution, meaning that once it reaches the first iteration that returns true, it does not continue the rest of the iterations, as they are unnecessary.

```js
const arr = ['be-', 'fe-', 'automated'];

const str = 'fe-cheese';
const oi = arr.some(a => str.indexOf(a) > -1) ? 'cheese' : 'meat';

console.log(oi);
```

Verify that at least one of the elements is present (indexOf) in the provided string.

Comment: why not just use `.indexOf()` for full browser support? Also, shouldn't you be checking with `.toLowerCase()`?

Comment: You can use `indexOf` - I originally had that, but changed it to `includes` based on comments. You can use `toLowerCase` as well, if you want to ignore case sensitivity. OP didnt specify they wanted to ignore case, so I didnt.

Comment: @tymeJV True, I guess I was assuming case insensitivity because of partial matching, but you're right - I don't know if that's a safe assumption to make unless we get more details from the OP